# Inserting the very special unicode character "Left Half Black Star" (aka U+2BE8) in text

Tags: python, unicode, special-characters, unicode-version, half-star

I built an app in Python - though this might be a more general question - writing stars into a text. I can write ☆ and ★ easily but I need the half-star, too. So far all my efforts have been a failure, so I ask.

Here is a table of the most important information about these characters.

|  | Black Star ★ | White Star ☆ | Left Half Black Star |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Code | 2605 | 2606 | 2BE8 |
| utf-8 code | E2 98 85 | E2 98 86 | E2 AF A8 |
| Unicode version | 1.1 (1993) | 1.1 (1993) | 11 (2018) |

This works for simple stars:

```
print((b'black star: \xE2\x98\x85').decode("utf-8"))
```

This almost works for simple stars (would be nice if somebody could explain though why the black star text is converted to `"汢捡⁫瑳牡›"`.)

```
` print((b'black star: \x05\x26').decode("utf-16"))`
```

This is a total failure resulting in the general character of non-recognized situations: ⯨ instead of my expectation of the half-full star.

```
`print((b'half black star: \xE2\xAF\xA8').decode("utf-8"))`
```

Same error on the console and writing into the `txt` file.
I think it might be the version of the Unicode, but I am not sure. I guess what is written is the correct character but the display of it fails. Is it? Whatever, the question is how can I actually make it work?

Comment: If the font you are using (in the console or when viewing a text file) does not have a glyph for the LEFT HALF BLACK STAR character, then the character won't be displayed.

Comment: The black and white stars were defined in Unicode 1.1. The half star is from Unicode 11.0.  It simply takes time for new characters to make their way into common availability - the half star doesn't work on my computer, either.

Comment: `.decode('utf-16')` -- why UTF-16? That's one obvious mistake decoding the black star. The byte string you apply that to also seems to mix UTF-8/ASCII and UTF-16

Comment: AS indicated what fonts are being used will impact on whether it is rendered. And choosing the right encoding is important when you are decoding bytes. The string equivalents `print('\u2BE8')` and `print('⯨')` work fine on macOS.

Comment: Even `print((b'\xE2\xAF\xA8').decode("utf-8")` works for me.

Comment: Actually, your post says "the general character of non-recognized situations: ⯨ instead of my expectation of the half-full star" and that symbol *is* a half-star for me.

Comment: @wRAR: What font do you use that includes the half star character?

Comment: @mzjn Chrome suggests that Noto Sans Symbols2 was used.